# Parsing html data into python list for manipulation

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to read in html websites and extract their data.  For example, I would like to read in the EPS (earnings per share) for the past 5 years of companies.  Basically, I can read it in and can use either BeautifulSoup or html2text to create a huge text block.  I then want to search the file -- I have been using re.search -- but can't seem to get it to work properly.  Here is the line I am trying to access:

EPS (Basic)\n13.4620.6226.6930.1732.81\n\n

So I would like to create a list called EPS = [13.46, 20.62, 26.69, 30.17, 32.81].

Thanks for any help.

```
from stripogram import html2text
from urllib import urlopen
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

ticker_symbol = 'goog'
url = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/'
full_url = url + ticker_symbol + '/financials'  #build url

text_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(full_url).read()) #read in 

text_parts = text_soup.findAll(text=True)
text = ''.join(text_parts)

eps = re.search("EPS\s+(\d+)", text)
if eps is not None:
    print eps.group(1)
```

Comment: The html after I soup.prettify() is:</a>
      EPS (Basic)
     </td>
     <td class="valueCell">
      13.46
     </td>
     <td class="valueCell">
      20.62
     </td>
     <td class="valueCell">
      26.69
     </td>
     <td class="valueCell">
      30.17
     </td>
     <td class="valueCell">
      32.81
     </td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use regex for parsing html. Use `BeautifulSoup` parser: find the cell with `rowTitle` class and `EPS (Basic)` text in it, then iterate over next siblings with `valueCell` class:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/goog/financials'
text_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read()) #read in

titles = text_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'rowTitle'})
for title in titles:
    if 'EPS (Basic)' in title.text:
        print [td.text for td in title.findNextSiblings(attrs={'class': 'valueCell'}) if td.text]
```

prints:

```
['13.46', '20.62', '26.69', '30.17', '32.81']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is a really nice and simple solution.  But when I run it I get an extra u character in the output: [u'13.46', u'20.62', u'26.69', u'30.17', u'32.81']  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a very different approach.  We use LXML for scraping html pages

One of the reasons we switched was because BS was not being maintained for a while - or I should say updated.

In my test I ran the following

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from collections import OrderedDict
page_as_string = requests.get('http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/goog/financials').content

tree = html.fromstring(page_as_string)
```

Now I looked at the page and I see the data is divided into two tables.  Since you want EPS, I noted that it is in the second table.  We could write some code to sort this out programmatically but I will leave that for you.

```
tables = [ e for e in tree.iter() if e.tag == 'table']
eps_table = tables[-1]
```

now I noticed that the first row has the column headings, so I want to separate all of the rows

```
table_rows = [ e for e in eps_table.iter() if e.tag == 'tr']
```

now lets get the column headings:

```
column_headings =[ e.text_content() for e in table_rows[0].iter() if e.tag == 'th']
```

Finally we can map the column headings to the row labels and cell values

```
my_results = []
for row in table_rows[1:]:
    cell_content = [ e.text_content() for e in row.iter() if e.tag == 'td']
    temp_dict = OrderedDict()
    for numb, cell in enumerate(cell_content):
        if numb == 0:
            temp_dict['row_label'] = cell.strip()
         else:
            dict_key = column_headings[numb]
            temp_dict[dict_key] = cell

    my_results.append(temp_dict)
```

now to access the results

```
for row_dict in my_results:
    if row_dict['row_label'] == 'EPS (Basic)':
        for key in row_dict:
            print key, ':', row_dict[key]   


row_label :  EPS (Basic)
2008 : 13.46
2009 : 20.62
2010 : 26.69
2011 : 30.17
2012 : 32.81
5-year trend :
```

Now there is still more to do, for example I did not test for squareness  (number of cells in each row is equal).

Finally I am a novice and I suspect others will advise more direct methods of getting at these elements (xPath or cssselect) but this does work and it gets you everything from the table in a nice structured manner.

I should add that every row from the table is available, they are in the original row order.  The first item (which is a dictionary) in the my_results list has the data from the first row, the second item has the data from the second row etc.

When I need a new build of lxml I visit a page maintained by a really nice guy at [UC-IRVINE](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Financials?s=CLLN:LSE&subview=BalanceSheet'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

table = soup.find('table', {'data-ajax-content' : 'true'})

data = []

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cells]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print df

dictframe = df.to_dict()

print dictframe
```

The above code will give you a DataFrame from the webpage and then uses that to create a python dictionary.