# Scraping an HTML table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to scrape the data in a table on the FT website, but I cannot get my code to work. I've been through other similar questions here on Stack Overflow, and while they have helped, it's beyond my skill to get the code working.

I'm looking to scrape the table and output to a list of dicts, or a dict of dicts, which I would then put into a pandas DataFrame.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

I want to:

1. Scrape the table
2. strip out the html tags
3. return a dict where
   the first cell of each row is the key, and the rest are values of the
   key

So far I can do (1), (2) I see as more of a cleanup exercise, shouldn't be too hard, (3) is where I have issues. Some of the rows contain only one entry because they are section headings, but are not marked up as such in the html, so the standard dict comprehensions I've seen in other answers are returning either an error, because key with no values, or setting the first entry as the key for the all the rest of the data.

The table is [here](http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Financials?s=CLLN:LSE&subview=BalanceSheet).

My code so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Financials?s=CLLN:LSE&subview=BalanceSheet').read())



table = soup.find('table', {'data-ajax-content' : 'true'})


for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        print cell.findAll(text = True)
```

Which gets me this kind of output:

```
[u'Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2013']
[u'2013']
[u'2012']
[u'2011']
[u'ASSETS']
[u'Cash And Short Term Investments']
[u'416']
[u'660']
[u'495']
```

I have tried:

```
rows = iter(table)

headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]

for row in rows:
    values = [col.text for col in row]
    print dict(zip(headers, values))
```

which may work, but I'm getting:

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authorization Required,

which I assume is because I'm behind a corporate proxy.

EDIT:

I tried the code above from home, and it gets this:

> {u'Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2013201320122011': u'ASSETS'}
>       {u'Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2013201320122011': u'LIABILITIES'}
>       {u'Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2013201320122011': u'SHAREHOLDERS EQUITY'}

which is tantalisingly close, but has only captured the first row of each section.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to python, so if you have time to explain your answer, that will also meet with my gratitude.

EDIT:

I've read around a bit more and tried a few more things:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'data-ajax-content' : 'true'})

rows = table.findAll('tr')

dict_for_series = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows}

print dict_for_series
```

Which results in:

```
{<tr><td class="label">Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2013</td><td>2013</td><td>2012</td><td>2011</td></tr>: [<tr class="section even"><td colspan="4">ASSETS</td></tr>, <tr class="odd"><td class="label">Cash And Short Term Investments</td><td>416</td><td>660</td><td>495</td></tr>, <tr class="even"><td class="label">Total Receivables, Net</td><td>1,216</td><td>1,122</td><td>1,102</td></tr>, <tr class="odd"><td class="label">Total Inventory</td><td>49</td><td>55</td><td>72</td><
```

In this case it seems the code sets the first entry as the key, and the rest as values.

Another attempt:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'data-ajax-content' : 'true'})

rows = table.findAll('tr')


d = []

for row in rows:
    d.append(row.findAll('td'))

rowsdict = {t[0]:t[1:] for t in d}

dictSer = Series(rowsdict)

dictframe = DataFrame(dictSer)

print dictframe
```

Which results in:

```
0
<td class="label">Fiscal data as of Dec 31 2013</td>                     [<td>2013</td>, <td>2012</td>, <td>2011</td>]
<td colspan="4">ASSETS</td>                                                                                         []
<td class="label">Cash And Short Term Investments</td>                      [<td>416</td>, <td>660</td>, <td>495</td>]
<td class="label">Total Receivables, Net</td>                         [<td>1,216</td>, <td>1,122</td>, <td>1,102</td>]
```

which is very close to what I want, the structure is almost right, but judging by the placement of the square brackets, this is treating all the values ie `<td>1,216</td>` as a single cell.

Anyway, I'll keep playing around and trying to make it work, but if anyone has any pointers, please let me know!

Comment: This question is very similar to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709058/parsing-html-data-into-python-list-for-manipulation

Comment: @WarrenLamont: it is relatively similar I agree, but the problem im having is how to iterate over the rows and cells to produce a dict which i can put into a DataFrame. Im not certain at what level the iterations should be to capture the 'td' cells, nor how to get the first cell to be the key of each dict.

Comment: dear oboi did you find a solution now!?